# How to route to two different 'Action' functions in same controller using annotation - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

Recently I shifted from Symfony 2.4 to Symfony 2.7

So I was following the new docs. Now say I have 2 `action functions` in same controller.

```
public function indexAction() {}

public function changeRateAction()
```

Previously I would have route them using `routing.yml`

```
change_interest_rate_label:
    path: /change_interest_rate
    defaults: { _controller: appBundle:appInterestRateChange:index }

change_interest_rate_action_label:
    path: /change_interest_rate_and_archived_action
    defaults: { _controller: appBundle:appInterestRateChange:changeRate }
```

Now in 2.7 docs, annotations are encourages. Inside `controller` file

```
/**
 * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
 */
```

This will fire the action method contains in the controller file. But how can I write annotations for 2 methods for different urls included in the same controller file ?

That means I have `indexAction` & `changeRateAction` in same controller file. I want to route url `/home` with index function and `/change` with changeRate function. How to do this using annotations ? I know how to do this using `routing.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the annotation routing **on a method, not a controller**, really.

You just specify the route before every method. In your case it would be something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction() {
    ...
}

/**
 * @Route("/change", name="changerate")
 */
public function changeRateAction() {
    ...
}
```

Be sure to read more about routing in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Ahh! missed it. Perfect. Thanks.